# Tabs dinamicas de Bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-blade

Buenas tardes tengo un problema que la verdad no se como abordarlo.

Tengo una base de datos con unas categorias y otra con unas rutinas, las asocio por una columna, creo que esto no viene al caso así que no detallo más.

Tengo en mi controlador una función que saca las categorias y luego empiezo a iterar del siguiente modo:

**Primero itero las categorias en los enlaces de los tabs**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 flexTabs" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    @foreach ($categorias as $item)
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}" id="pills-{{ $item->slug }}-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-{{ $item->slug }}" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-{{ $item->slug }}" aria-selected="true">{{ $item->valor }}</a>
      </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

**Después itero los diferentes contenidos del siguiente modo, que van asociados con el `slug` de cada categoría.**

```
<div id="pills-tabContent" class="he100 tab-content">
    @foreach ($categorias as $item)
       <div id="pills-{{ $item->slug }}" class="he100 tab-pane fade {{ $loop->first ? 'show' : '' }} {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-{{ $item->slug }}-tab">
          <div class="row he801">
            <div class="col-6 he100">
               <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide he100 carruF1Wai" data-ride="carousel">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators edit-indicators">
                     @foreach ($item->rutinas as $key => $item2)
                       @if ($item2->destacado == 1 && $item2->estado == 1)
                          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
                        @endif
                     @endforeach
                   </ol>
                   <div class="carousel-inner bordeCarrousel he100">
                      @foreach ($item->rutinas as $item2)
                         @if ($item2->destacado == 1 && $item2->estado == 1)
                            <div class="carousel-item itemMyCarrousel heinhe {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }} he100">
                             @if ($item2->esVideo == 1)
                                <a href="#modalVideo" class="video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVideo" data-src="{{ $item2->video }}">
                             @else
                                <a href="#modal{{ $item2->id }}" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{ $item2->id }}">
                          @endif
                          <div id="overlayTraining"></div>
                          <div class="overRuti2"></div>
                          <img class="d-block w-100 imgSlideTrai" src="{{ asset("{$item2->foto}") }}" alt="First slide">
                          <div class="cont-slid-trai">
                             <h2>{{ $item2->titulo }}</h2>
                             <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ $item2->tiempo }}</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="cont-slid-trai2">
                             <h2>{{ $item->valor }}</h2>
                          </div>
                         </a>
                         </div>
                      @endif
                     @endforeach
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 he100">
                  <div class="row he100 scrollTips2 minisF1Wai" id="minisF1Wai">
                     @foreach ($item->rutinas as $item2)
                       @if ($item2->destacado == 0 && $item2->estado == 1)
                       <div class="col-6 he48 scrollTips">
                         @if ($item2->esVideo == 1)
                           <a href="#modalVideo" class="video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVideo" data-src="{{ $item2->video }}">
                         @else
                           <a href="#modal{{ $item2->id }}" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal{{ $item2->id }}">
                          @endif
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="he100 cuadrosMinRutines">
                            <div class="overRuti"></div>
                            <img class="miniaturasTraining" src="{{ asset("{$item2->foto}") }}">
                         <div class="container-miniaturas center">
                           <h2>{{ $item2->titulo }}</h2>
                           <small>{{ $item->valor }}</small>
                           <hr>
                           <h3><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{ $item2->tiempo }}</h3>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                       </a>
                      </div>
                      @endif
                     @endforeach
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
           </div>
         @endforeach
     </div>
```

Para detallarlo un poco mejor:
Primero itero las categorias,hay utilizo el `loop` para obtener el primero marcado como activo. Luego vuelvo a iterar lo mismo pero para que itere los contenidos de las tabs. Dentro de este `foreach` vuelvo a hacer otro para sacar las rutinas que están dentro de esa categoría `$item->rutinas as $key => $item2`. Lo primero que tiene cada tab es un slider donde itero los destacados, es un slider de Bootstrap entonces intento utilizar el loop del mismo modo que antes. La siguiente parte son cuatro cuadros donde itero el resto de no destacados.

Pensaba que me funcionaba todo bien, hasta que me di cuenta, que para que el slider funcione en cada tab la primera fila de cada categoria a de ser destacado, si es el segundo por ejemplo no pone el `active`.

Es muy dificil explicaros todo, no se si así es posible entender lo que sucede. Yo creo que el loop al haber más de un foreach no funciona bien.

Tambien pienso que como la clase `active` se la pone al `$loop->first` al no ser el primero destacado ya se trunca

Comment: podrias mostrar como tienes la vista y que quieres hacer, es un poco complejo de entender